# The Symbol that Looks Like an F?

Tags: probability, statistics, brownian-motion

What is the symbol that looks like a capital f, F, which is used to prove the martingale:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a capital $F$ in a calligraphic font.

Comment: Without any context this is just a guess, but it might be a $\sigma$-field?

Comment: @dinosaur It was used to prove martingale

Comment: In general - filtration. In this particular - hard to say.

Comment: `$\mathcal{F}$` to produce $\mathcal{F}$ for a [filtration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics)#Measure_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that $\mathcal{F}_s^B$ is a *Brownian Filtration*, with respective time $s$. See for instance *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*- section 2.7, from Karatzas and Shreve.

You can also see this notation being used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103748/what-is-the-difference-between-filtration-for-a-brownian-motion-and-filtratio/1103759#1103759).